# Windows On-Prem Active Directory - Moving from GPO based Password Policies to Fine Grained Access

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, password-policy

It has become a requirement for us to have more than one password policy on the same domain. I have been doing some research and it looks like the way to achieve this is through Fine Grained Password Policies. I can see plenty of articles online which explain it and there is a tool for doing this now, rather than use ADSI Edit as for example https://specopssoft.com/blog/create-fine-grained-password-policy-active-directory/. We already have a GPO based password policy.

My question is how to we move from the GPO password policy to Fine-Grained? Will it cause a mess with the security or potentially lock people out? Can you just create a Fine-Grained policy in addition to the GPO one and attach to an OU or will that be overridden? Do we have to completely remove the GPO and create Fine-Grained policies? I can't see anything online which explains how to move from one to the other and what the implications are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine grained password policies will overrule 'generic' or GPO password policies.

You can also easily assign these new fine grained policies to a group of users to test with.

Comment: Thanks, is the tool from the link still valid? I prefer not to mess around with ADSI Edit.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use Active Directory Administration Center for that as that article describes.